# Does ng-repeat set a watch for items inside a {{ }}?

Tags: angularjs

Given the following:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="row in grid.view track by row.problemId = (grid.data | filter:isProblemInRange)">
    <td>{{ row.problemId }}</td>
    <td>{{ getUser(row.createdBy) }}</td>
    ...
```

My table displays very slowly with over 500 rows. Can anyone tell me, does ng-repeat set a watch for both of these columns?  What I am thinking is that it might be better for me to change the grid.data source so that it includes the user rather than have AngularJS check this on the fly. Would that improve performance?

Comment: I highly recommend that you provide full set of data in this case if there is no particular reason why userdata shouldnt exist in your when launching ng-repeat. This is absolutely performance bottle neck.

Comment: Yes. Ngrepeat watces for any changes in list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would set watches for one column and it will watch 500 times per digest loop. If the getUser() method isn't very performant I suggest to get the user object from the data source instead of getUser.

Check out this blog post. It might help https://github.com/scalyr/angular